# getch() takes input before printing

Tags: python

I am trying to print a message and then take a single character from the user as an input using the following snippet.

```
import getch

print("Enter a character: ", end="")
char = getch.getch()
print("You entered", char)
```

But for some reasons, it asks for an input first. After giving an input it  shows the message. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your print buffer isn't being flushed. Try this:

```
import getch

print("Enter a character: ", end="", flush=True)
char = getch.getch()
print("You entered", char)
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Sorry if I sound stupid, but what is a print buffer?

Comment: Some useful reading [here](https://realpython.com/python-print/#buffering-print-calls)

Comment: Thank you very much.